# Error: package meteor-scss is built for incompatible architecture

Tags: meteor

Getting this error while running meteor.js 0.9.3.1 after installing the package matthew:foundation5-sass

error: package `meteor-scss` is built for incompatible architecture

Comment: Provide content of your .meteor/packages file and smart.json file

Comment: sorry but don't have any file called smart.json , is it star.json ?

Comment: smart.json is where you store private packages and meteorite packages. That is alright, just put .meteor/packages

Comment: `# Meteor packages used by this project, one per line.
#
# 'meteor add' and 'meteor remove' will edit this file for you,
# but you can also edit it by hand.

meteor-platform
autopublish
insecure
matthew:foundation5-sass`

Comment: do you have meteor-scss folder in /packages directory?

Comment: Fixed ..just updated fourseven to latest version